# Is it possible to set initial state to a simulink model to do simulations?

Tags: control-system, power-engineering, simulink

Consider that I have built an electrical circuit, or a power system or any other at Simulink and to do simulations, Simulink should work in the sense that it builds a state space model of the system, right? If that is the case, is it possible to set an initial condition of this model? And more, is it possible to know what are the state variables of the model built by Simulink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [set_param](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/set_param.html) to initialize your blocks

Usage: *set_param('model_name/system_name/subsystem_name/.../block_name', 'parameter', 'value')*